# jQuery UI inside ajax div

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

i have a site with links that look like this: onClick = ajax('link.html','contentdiv')

but i want to use jquery ui tabs inside the contentdiv, i tried even to put all the code inside the html but nothing, i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs({});
```

and also:

```
$((function() {
```

what should i put in the index.html and the link.html to make it work? the #tabs div is inside the link.html

thanks

Comment: Try to put some more code of the problem. You are mixing some existing javascript with the jQuery I suppose. Do you have any errors on the console? Put them as well. Maybe doing a simpler jQuery example first will also help.

Comment: hm, at the index.html i got: $(document).ready(function() { $("#tabs").tabs(); }); inside the index.html theres a div called CONTENTDIV that open my ajax content so i click on a link (link.html), the CONTENTDIV gets the content (all ok until now), but i have a jquery ui tabs inside the link.html, but it doesnt work.......if i open the link.html outside the CONTENTDIV its all ok.....the link.html have the <div id="#tabs>.....i even tried to put the jquery.js and jqueryui.js in both files but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to do that anymore.. just simply use [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) method, which they created in new release, it will work on new div also

```
$('.newDiv').live('click', contendDiv);
```

**EDITED:**
if you adding tabs inside ajax content after click, then do following

```
$('.newDiv').live('click', function () {
      // following can be ajax content or static content
      var content_div = '<div>...<div id="tab"></div..</div>';

      var selector = $(content_div);
      $(selector).find('#tab').tab({});
      return $(selector).html(); // add this in your final html content, it will have tabs ready.
});
```

Comment: yeah it worked using live(), the problem is that only after i click on the tab she became a real "jquery ui tabs"
gonna try something with that append html

Comment: hmm not sure what you doing, but so far i understand from reading above things.. you are loading ajax content in another div, which has tabs init and tabs dont show properly, until you click on it. if thats what it is, then get that div content and find the tab id init and then apply tabs method on it. i can show you example, if that is what you trying to do, if not, then please explain, so we can give proper answer :)

Comment: yeah i think thats right, my code is: http://pastebin.com/m77383369 - the "document ready" makes no diff btw

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your trying to initialize the tabs before they are available.  $(document).ready() from index.html will happen far before the user clicks the link and starts the ajax.

Try using something along these lines to make the tabify method wait until the html is available.

```
onclick = ajax({
             url:     'link.html',
             success: function (html) {
                          $('#contentdiv').append(html);
                          $('#tabs, #contentdiv').tabs();
             }
          });
```

Comment: didnt work, but i kind like made work with basit's code
but there's a problem, i described above